# Prevent jQuery Mobile Page navigation (PhoneGap) IF

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Using PhoneGap...

I would like to find a way to prevent the navigation for data-role='page', if the user has no network connection.  I'm having a hard time finding any resources for this, am a few hours deep on google searching, although I could be using the wrong terms.

I want the user to only be able to navigate here if there is network connection:

```
  <div data-role="page" id="Location">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back">Incid..</a>
            <h1>
                Location</h1>
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" onclick="updateLoc()" data-theme="g">Use      Current</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <!--<div id="panel">
                <input id="target" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
                    </div>-->
            <div id="map_canvas">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Using this jQuery for `pageshow`:

```
$('#Location').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
  try {
    display();
  }
  catch (e) {
    log(e);
    alert(e);
  }
});
```

I know I should be able to catch the network status using if(navigator.network.connection.type == 'none'), but I'm having difficulty stopping the Location page from showing.

Comment: Can you not use $.mobile.changePage('#DifferentPage') and change the page if there is no network connection?

Comment: That, was a lot simpler than I made it.  Thanks @AndrewLively if you make that an answer I will Mark it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.mobile.changePage('#pageID')` to change the page depending on if the user has a network connection or not.